# Why React-router doesn't redirect immediately after calling browserHistory.push method ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is the code in my componentWillMount function:

```
   if(expression) {
      let path = '/something;
      browserHistory.push(path);
    } 
    let tokens = CookiesWrapper.getCookie('tokens');
    if (!tokens) {
      browserHistory.push('/login');
    }
```

When I debugging I see strange behavior with browserHistory.push method, It looks code is executed asynchronously.

When it comes to line 3. code continue with execution on line 4, and 5, it doesn't redirect me immediately after calling push method. Any ideas why this happening?

Comment: use a return, otherwise the execution flow will continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use a `return` the parser will continue to execute code (in this case it'll move on to your `let` declaration and `if` statement).

```
   if(expression) {
      let path = '/something';
      return browserHistory.push(path);
    } 
    let tokens = CookiesWrapper.getCookie('tokens');
    if (!tokens) {
      return browserHistory.push('/login');
    }
```